# Количество прогрессий в интервале

Tags: c, математика, счетчики, прогрессия

В файле дано три целых числа ,  и . Требуется
**найти количество возрастающих арифметических прогрессий, у которых ровно  элементов
лежит в диапазоне от  до  включительно.**
В данной задаче нужно рассматривать только прогрессии, у которых все элементы целые.
Считается, что у арифметической прогрессии есть первый элемент, но нет последнего: она
бесконечная. Если две прогрессии начинаются с разного элемента, то их нужно считать
различными.
Достаточно долго бьюсь с кодом, но получается какая-то ерунда... Посоветуйте, что можно сделать/исправить, пожалуйста :)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main(){
    int L, R, K, N, i, a, b;
    N=0;
    scanf("%d %d %d", &L, &R, &K);
    if(K==1){
        N=R-L;
    }
    else if (K>1){
        b=ceil((R-L)/(K-1));
        for(i=0; i<=(R-L); i+=b){
            if((i>=L)&&((i+(K-1)*b)<L))
                N++;
        }
        
        
    }
    printf("%d", N);
}
```

Comment: Приведите код ввода хотя бы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**короче говоря, вот какое решение оказалось верным**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int L, R, K, i, d, j, k, a1, a2;
scanf ("%d %d %d", &L, &R, &K);
a1=a2=d=k=0;
d=R-L;
for (j=1; j<=d; j++)
{
    for (i=L; i<R; i++)
    {
     a1 = i+j*(K-1);
     a2 = i+j*K;
     if ((a1<=R) && (a2>R) )
     k=k+1;
    }
}
printf ("%d", k);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Не ответ! но в комментарий не помещаюсь :(

Ну, давайте подумаем. Итак, что такое прогрессия? Это числа

```
a, a+b, a+2b ... a+(K-1)b ...
```

(Тут показано ровно K членов) Какие условия накладывает задача? Первый и последний элемент должен быть внутри диапазона, а перед первым и после последнего - вне.

Т.е.

```
a >= L
a +(K-1)b <= R
a-b < L
a+Kb > R
b > 0
```

А теперь подумайте, как найти все возможные **целочисленные** решения, или хотя бы посчитать, сколько их...

Кстати, для простоты, не меняя общности, можно считать, что ищем количество в диапазоне от 0 до R-L.

Из приведенных уравнений получаем, что

```
(R-L)/(K-1) >= b > (R-L)/(K+1)
```

Ну, и

```
0 <= a <= R-L-(K-1)*b
a > R - K*b
```

Значит, навскидку

```
int Count(int L, int R, int K)
{
    R-=L;
    int count = 0;
    for(int b = R/(K-1); b > R/(K+1); --b)
    {
        int a = R-K*b;
        if (a < 0) a = 0;
        int aa = R - (K-1)*b;
        if (aa-a > 0) count += aa-a;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Попробуйте, может, чего и не учел...

Comment: Получается, мы используем цикл for, чтобы посмотреть соответствие условию? Но как в этот цикл впихнуть то, что перед первым и после последнего? Не совсем понимаю :(

Comment: Начните с того, что оцените значение `b` - оно должно быть *около* (R-L)/(K-1), так ведь? Прикиньте, каким оно может быть, а каким - категорически нет. Отсюда для разных доступных `b` уже можно начинать искать `a`.

Comment: Кстати, чисто теоретически есть ситуация, когда решений бесконечно много - например, только один элемент прогрессии в диапазоне :)

Comment: В правку добавлен код, но, похоже, все равно где-то не догоняю. Хоть частично-то где-то мелькает суть?

Comment: См. дополненный ответ. Есть где-то тестирующая система? Дайте URL.

Comment: Тестирующей системы нет :( Но, например при вводе 10 20 3 должно выйти 10. В моей программе выходит 0, а если тестировать вашу - exitcode 0

Comment: Ну, тогда проверяйте сами. А вообще - старайтесь не быть [гуглопрограммистом](https://habr.com/ru/post/521104/), дали идеи - надо работать самому, а не ждать готовый код...

Comment: Ну, как говорится, вся ночь впереди :) Спасибо большое, буду оттачивать мастерство свое

Comment: 10 20 3 - OK, давайте смотреть. Я вручную нашел 10 15 20, 10 14 18, 11 15 19, 12 16 20, 12 15 18 - итого 5 прогрессий. Столько, сколько дает и мой код `Count(10,20,3)`. Что я не вижу? Где еще 5 прогрессий? Если перечислите - буду смотреть, а пока - по моим прикидкам - дало верный ответ.

Comment: Вот такие получились: 10 14 18, 10 15, 20, 11 15 19, 12 15 18, 12 16 20, 13 16 19, 14 17 20, 15 17 19, 16 18 20, 18 19 20. То есть их 10, если не ошибаюсь

Comment: 13 16 19 - не годится, потому что если ее продолжить влево - это 10 13 16 19, я такие не считал... тогда понятна разница. Сейчас, извините, нет времени дорешивать, если напомните завтра - посижу немного..

Comment: Если самостоятельно не смогу решить к завтрашнему дню - конечно напомню, спасибо :)

Comment: Получилось! Добавила верное решение в ответы

Comment: @A_Hatake Искренне рад за вас!

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, не

> Если две прогрессии начинаются с разного элемента, то их нужно считать различными.

А если эти разные элементы, с которых они начинаются, взаимнопросты.

Иначе, если найдется хотя бы одна прогрессия, их сразу же найдется и бесконечность, потому что:

```
a, a + b, a + 2b, ...
a - b, a, a + b, a + 2b, ...
a - 2b, a - b, a, a + b, a + 2b, ...
⋮
```

"пройдут" по одинаковым элементам.

Во-вторых, @Harry видимо всё правильно написал. У меня получилось так:

```
int Count(int L, int R, int K)
{
    R -= L;
    int count = 0;
    for(int b = R / (K - 1); R / b < K + 1; --b)
    {
        if (R / b < K)
            count += 1 + R % b; // учитываем прогрессию + её все возможные "сдвиги"
        else
            // максимально сдвинуть прогрессию можно на b - 1 (иначе в диапазон залезет элемент слева)
            // минимально прогрессию необходимо сдвинуть на R % b + 1, чтобы сдвинуть K + 1 'ый элемент за правую границу диапазона
            // итого, b - 1 - (R % b + 1) сдвигов
            // так как включительно, +1
            count += b - 1 - (R % b + 1) + 1;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Ваш код для 10,20,3 дает ответ 4 - при том что таких прогрессий 5:10 15 20, 10 14 18, 11 15 19, 12 16 20, 12 15 18

Comment: @Harry Вы правы, действительно надо снижать b именно до R / b < K + 1, а не K и сдвигать из диапазона лишний последний элемент.

Comment: @Harry исправил

Answer (score 0):

Учитывая понятное теперь благодаря комментариям условие:

```
int Count(int L, int R, int K)
{
    R -= L;
    int count = 0;
    while (R > 0)
    {
        count += R / (K - 1) - R / K;
        --R;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: При тестировании данного кода в онлайн-компиляторе, получилось exit code 0. Думаю, что-то по времени не проходит

Comment: @A_Hatake Исправил. Теперь работает за линейное время.

Comment: Неа, все равно по времени не проходит :(